# Grouping Expert, Current date against start date

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having trouble grouping certain results in a work in progress report that arranges by start date, I have grouped using fixed values before but because the dates keep moving I am unsure what to do.

The start date is WIP_Schedule.Start_Date

the groups I am trying to create are:

[Group1] Overdue = the current date has passed the start date.

[Group2] (Yet to be named) = the current date 2 week period prior to the start date

[Group3] To Do = the current date after the two week period prior to the start date.

I am after a works instruction on how to achieve this.

I know this isn't a lot of information, if you require any more please ask.

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty straightforward requirement, so you should be able to figure it out by searching the web. However, I'll give you part of the answer and hopefully you can figure it out.

Start by creating a formula to figure out the status of the date.

`If {WIP_Schedule.Start_Date} > current date then "Overdue"
Else......`

Then you can group based on that formula. All you have to do is figure out the rest of the formula.

Comment: I know how to do that, I am having trouble with the "Start date up until two weeks prior to the start date" and the "two week prior to the start date onwards.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly then the rest of the formula would be like this... if currentdate <= StartDate and currentdate >= DateAdd("d",-14,StartDate) then "Yet to be named"
else
if currentdate < DateAdd("d",-14,StartDate) then "To Do"